# Python crashes with LD_PRELOAD and ThreadSanitizer library

Tags: python, sanitizer, thread-sanitizer

I have a scenario where a python script loads a shared object on a Ubuntu 20 x64 system. The shared object is instrumented with thread sanitizer. However, once the libary loads it spawns a "cannot allocate memory in static TLS block" error. The usual method to deal with this is to preload libtsan.so.0 with LD_PRELOAD but prepending this to the python call will yield a segmentation fault.

Are there special precautions for using tsan instrumented so with python?

Regards